# How should I structure nested db tables?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, nestjs

Right now I have 3 tables: users, workspaces and cards.

```
users
---
id
name
password

workspaces
---
id
title
ownerId

cards
---
id
title
workspaceId
ownerId
```

Each user has many workspaces and each workspace has many cards. When I want to update a card, I should check if the user is the owner of this card. So, which approach is better: to add ownerId to each card in db table or to make 2 requests in order to get info about the owner id?
Here is the guard I have right now:

```
@Injectable()
export class CardOwnershipGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly cardService: CardService,
  ) {}
  
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest() as RequestWithUser;
    const userId = request.user.id;
    const userIsOwner = await this.cardService.checkOwner(userId, request.params.id);
    if (!userIsOwner) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

And the checkOwner func:

```
async checkOwner(userId: string, cardId: string) {
    const card = await this.cardRepository.findOne(cardId);
    return card.ownerId === userId;
}
```

Comment: Neither is good. Keep the attributes where they belong and run a single query that joins both tables.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I have created bi-directional relationships and now I'm making only 1 request with joins, I just wanted to make sure if it is a good practice